# how to fix policy claim?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I followed this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp

Next, i added a policy claim below . And decorated my home controller with :     [Authorize(Policy = "CanAccessUsersGroup")]

But i get a error :  https://localhost:44321/Account/AccessDenied?ReturnUrl=%2F
What am i missing ?
Thanks, Peter

```
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                "CanAccessUsersGroup",
                policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireClaim("groups", "c50bc813-f8a7-442f-83ab-eeb406474c08"));
        });
```

Comment: Did you add that Claim to the user/group that you are using to log in or are you sure that that claim exists for that user/group?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The user exists in the AAD group.
Do you mean something like this : 

var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

// Add custom user claims here
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("myCustomClaim", "value of claim"));

Comment: Yes. If user or his group doesn't have the claim that is required by policy you will get access denied. Your user/group require claim "groups" with value "c50bc813-f8a7-442f-83ab-eeb406474c08".

Comment: how do i determine if the user is in the specified group?   do I put this logic into the startup.cs  ? any examples ?

Comment: in a previous project, i did not have to create claims.

Comment: Use online tool like https://jwt.io/ to check your id token or check user claims in controller after authentication to check whether you have groups claim . And also do you set  `groupMembershipClaims ` in application's manifest in AD portal ?